# Remote Installation : Windows Installer

Tags: windows-installer

I have a requirement to install my windows application on remote windows machine; I see that couple of people have done using WMI and others; But I am not exactly happy with such a hand made solution; It would much easier if Windows Installer can do it; If it can be done using WMI and other ways, why is the Windows Installer not doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Installer is a service that installs MSI databases. It's not it's job to be a software distribution system.  For that Microsoft included [GPO deployment](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102) in Active Directory and more powerful tools such as Systems Center Configuration Manager (SCCM).

You can also use tools such as PSEXEC or interact with WMI or PowerShell to reach out to a machine and invoke MSIEXEC to run an MSI.  But at the end of the day Windows Installer doesn't concern itself with this space.

Comment: I could use PSEXEC but it always copies the installer file to the system folder; is there a way to push it to share other than the system folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the administrative share enabled then you could always push the file into a folder on the remote machines, e.g. \\hostname\c$\temp or somesuch and then use WMI, PSEXEC or remote PowerShell call to execute msiexec remotely.